# pandas series to csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following pandas series:

```
0        [[1, 11283, 01, 5], [2,5, 1, 1]]
1        [[6, 33, 21, 2], [11283, 01, 5,1]] 
2        [[8430, 01, 2, 2],[2, 1, 1, 1]]
```

I need to save this as csv but csv rows should be something similar to following:

```
1, 11283, 01, 5
2,5, 1, 1
6, 33, 21, 2
11283, 01, 5,1
8430, 01, 2, 2
2, 1, 1, 1
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: You have a `pandas.Series` of a list of lists?

Comment: yes. pandas.series of list of list,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
df = pd.Series([[[1, 11283, 1, 5], [2,5, 1, 1]], 
                [[6, 33, 21, 2], [11283, 1, 5,1]], 
                [[8430, 1, 2, 2],[2, 1, 1, 1]]])

df.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(drop=True)
```

As @jezrael, @coldspeed, and many other pandas gods have suggested use the following over `apply(pd.Series)`:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.tolist()).stack().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
0    [1, 11283, 1, 5]
1        [2, 5, 1, 1]
2      [6, 33, 21, 2]
3    [11283, 1, 5, 1]
4     [8430, 1, 2, 2]
5        [2, 1, 1, 1]
dtype: object
```

Comment: `df.apply(pd.Series)` rather not, because slow - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35491399/2901002)

Comment: such a beauty !

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist()).stack().reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: @jezrael Thanks, I will drill that into my skull one of these days.  I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about `01` becoming `1`:

```
df = pd.Series([[[1, 11283, 1, 5], [2,5, 1, 1]], 
                [[6, 33, 21, 2], [11283, 1, 5,1]], 
                [[8430, 1, 2, 2],[2, 1, 1, 1]]])
flat_list = [item for sublist in df.tolist() for item in sublist if item not in (',','[',']')]
pd.DataFrame(flat_list).to_csv('your_path')
```